# How do foreigners get electrical service in the United States?

Tags: utilities

In the United States, at least in New England, to sign up for electrical service, the applicant must either be a US business with an EIN or a private person with a social security number.

What if a foreign entity or company needs electrical service and has neither of those things?

For example, a foreign consulate will need electrical service and for legal reasons will not have an EIN, and of course the ambassador or consular official managing the facility will not have a social security number.

Comment: Your assumption that the foreign consulate won't have an EIN seems questionable.  Foreign consulates employ local staff.  Furthermore, foreign ambassadors and consular officials may be able to get a social security number [for "a valid non-work reason"](https://www.ssa.gov/ssnumber/cards.htm).  This question may be better suited to [Law.SE].

Comment: It's more likely that an EIN or SSN is *expected* by the power company's front-line customer-service staff (since that's likely all they're trained for), but someone higher up is probably aware that it's not actually *required*.

Comment: According to this USA today article [https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2017/10/28/no-social-security-number-no-electricity/807471001/], this is indeed a problem for immigrants in some parts of the USA.

Answer (score 2):

Many utilities, but not all small municipal utility companies like those in Alexander Dunlap's [link](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2017/10/28/no-social-security-number-no-electricity/807471001/), [will accept an alternate form of identification](https://consumerist.com/2008/09/23/how-to-get-utilities-and-phone-service-without-giving-up-your-ssn/) such as a driver's license number or passport. They may also require a large deposit in such circumstances. The ID and deposit requirements may be defined in state utility regulations or may be a matter of utility policy.

While it's not required, the US State Department [encourages foreign consulate to obtain an EIN](https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/229358.pdf) for exactly these sorts of reasons, so I imagine they'd likely do that, particularly if it's the only way they can get electricity.